# What goes inside the 'unitName' of the @PersistenceContext annotation in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I'm very new to spring boot and was trying to use entity manager. When I saw the examples online, I almost always saw `@PersistenceContext(unitName="unit_name")` annotation on top of the entity manager instance created; what goes inside the unitName? Is it the name of the database I'm trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [Javadoc Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html)

> unitName
> (Optional) -  The name of the persistence unit as defined in the persistence.xml file.

If there is a persistence.xml file in the project, so you can specify this argument just like it's in the file. It's an optional parameter, so it's auto-selected if not informed.